# send with ajax a value changing array and compare it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I am trying to send with ajax the values of the clicked buttons. The values become inserted into an array named `$buttons` and should requested to `gamescreen.php`. After each new click ajax should update the array values. If I run this `echo count($buttons);` I get always `0` and not how it should a after a click changing number. What did I wrong or cant ajax used for something like this?

my console show after 5 clicks this:

> Yay it worked ["3", "4", "2", "1", "3"]

```
    <script>
        var values = [];
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.ui-btn').click(function() {
                values.push($(this).val());
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'gamescreen.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        buttons: values,
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        console.log('Yay it worked', values);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log('Something went wrong');
                    }
                });
            });
            // where X is your every X minutes
        });

        <?php
if (isset($_POST['buttons'])) {
            $code = 9472158;
            $arr1 = str_split($code);
            $buttons = $_POST['buttons'];
            $result1 = count($arr1);
            $result2 = count($buttons);

            if ($result1 == $result2)
            {
                //echo something in jquery language
            }
}
        ?>
    </script>
```

**my html:**

```
<div>
    <button name="btn1" type="submit" id="btn1" value="1" class="ui-btn"></button>
    <button name="btn2" type="submit" id="btn2" value="2" class="ui-btn"></button>
</div> // I have up to 9 buttons, thats only a piece
```

Comment: try to remove last comma in line >> buttons: values,<-- this comma

Comment: It wont change anything. :(

Comment: you still get Undefined index: buttons??

Comment: Is the code you have posted the contents of `gamescreen.php`? I don't quite follow your code, are you confused about the order in which things are executed? First the PHP code will be executed on the server, JavaScript and HTML are just plain text to your server. The server will have no memory of the PHP code once it has finished executing it. All the variables and arrays are destoyed, the only thing left is what is sent to the browser. The browser executes your JavaScript, which sends a request the server, which executes some more PHP. What is in this PHP code?

Comment: Yes thats a snippet of `gamescreen.php`.

Comment: Should I make it like that: `var values = [];

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.ui-btn').click(function() {
        values.push($(this).val());
   
   if (values.length == <?php echo($result1); ?>) {
    
    $('.ui-btn').addClass('disabled');
   }
    });
  // where X is your every X minutes
});` without ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the PHP in the same file as the $.ajax request but you sending the array to `gamescreen.php` so you need to do it like this;

### INDEX.PHP

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
       var values = [];
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('.ui-btn').click(function() {
                values.push($(this).val());
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'gamescreen.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {
                        buttons: values
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        console.log('Yay it worked', values);
                    },
                    error: function() {
                        console.log('Something went wrong');
                    }
                });
            });
            // where X is your every X minutes
        });
</script>

<div>
    <button name="btn1" type="submit" id="btn1" value="1" class="ui-btn"></button>
    <button name="btn2" type="submit" id="btn2" value="2" class="ui-btn"></button>
</div>
```

### GAMESCREEN.PHP

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST["buttons"])){

        $code = 9472158;
        $arr1 = str_split($code);
        $buttons = $_POST["buttons"];
        $result1 = count($arr1);
        $result2 = count($buttons);

        if ($result1 === $result2){
            //echo something in jquery language
        }

    }

?>
```